# ZSH - missing git icons

Tags: terminal, git, zsh

Hi I've just installed ZSH and it looks awesome but git icons are still missing and I don't know what I miss.

[image]

What I should do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have powerline font.

You can get it from [here](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/tree/develop/font)

After download, double click to install and set as **defalut font** & **non-ascii font**

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me when I unselected the option in iterm preferences to use a different font for non-ASCII text.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Missing icons in this case a *patched font* isn't installed which is dedicated for showing specific symbols for your shell.

You can either set yourself up easy with an available [repo](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/archive/master.zip). I should note that these patched fonts are for the `Powerline` extension and may or may not be compatible with other extensions.

If you wish to patch your own font, however, it's a little more involved:

1. Download [`fontpatcher`](https://github.com/powerline/fontpatcher/archive/develop.zip)
2. Using a package manager such as `homebrew`, install `fontforge` (`brew install fontforge`).
3. Patch your fonts by running the fontpatcher script like such: 
   `fontforge -script /path/to/fontpatcher.py MyFontFile.ttf`
4. Update your terminal configuration to use the patched font.

Answer (score 2):

Install Powerline font and then check this option in preference as in the image below[image]